# React native setup error. Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: react-native

I have followed the instructions https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

I can go into my avd and launch an emulator. However when I run `react-native run-android` I get the error:

Error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.

> - What went wrong:
>   Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>   Process command line: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/mattharris/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.1.1-all/cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst/gradle-6.1.1/lib/gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.1.1
>   Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

Unrecognized VM option 'CMSClassUnloadingEnabled'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

It states no emulators are installed but they are! Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this?

Comment: No a reinstall fixed it

Comment: what did you reinstall? Java? if yes i reinstall twice but my android emulator does not work.